# Is the controller being disposed after using ViewRenderer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewrendering

I'm using [ViewRenderer](https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs) to write view result to a file like so:

```
    public class WriteViewToFile
    {
        private DetailsController controller = ViewRenderer.CreateController<DetailsController>();

        public void WriteDataToFile(ContextDB db, DataViewModel model, string fileName)
        {

            string html = ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/Views/Details/TemplateForData.cshtml", model, controller.ControllerContext);

            File.WriteAllText(fileName, html);
            // controller.dispose();
        }
        public void WriteOtherToFile(ContextDB db, OtherViewModel model, string fileName)
        {

            string html = ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/Views/Details/TemplateForOther.cshtml", model, controller.ControllerContext);

            File.WriteAllText(fileName, html);
            // controller.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Should I add controller.dispose() in the end or is this done automatically? if yes, is there a way to dispose of it after any of the methods are called?

Answer (score 0):

You could separate that behavior into its own method:

```
public void WriteToFile(ContextDB db, DataViewModel model, string fileName)
{
    string html = RenderView(model);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, html);
}

private string RenderView(model)
{
    using(var controller = ViewRenderer.CreateController<DetailsController>())
    {
        return ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/Views/Details/Template.cshtml", 
            model, controller.ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

Now your controller is being created, used, and then disposed.

Comment: I use it with several different models, each has its own view. I'll update my question to clarify

Comment: In that case the path to the view would just be a parameter passed to `RenderView.

Comment: the model class is also different